# Initializate Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, image, button, initialization

Hello I am a beginner in Mathematica and I have a question about initialization of manipulate. I have code like this and I want to ask you, how to modify that code if I want have default picture saved in variable "image", but only in first use of this manipulate.

```
 Manipulate[
    Column[{
    Button["LoadPicture", image=Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]],Method -> "Queued"],
    image    
    }],{input,"Enter your number","Number:"}
    ]
```

I tried some condition where I want save there empty string and after loaded picture show that picture...like this:

```
 Manipulate[
    Column[{
    Button["LoadPicture", image=Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]],Method -> "Queued"],
    If[ImageQ[image]==False, image=""];
    image    
    }],{input,"Enter your number","Number:"}
    ]
```

but there always kernel crashed.

Comment: ye I can add this, but it still does not fix my problem

Comment: yes it still crashes

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 image,
 Button["LoadPicture", image = Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]], 
  Method -> "Queued"],
  {{ image, <<< PASTE the image here >>>> },None}
]
```

Here is how it looks like:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

i.e. first get the image you want as default,

[image: Mathematica graphics]

the copy-paste it directly inside Manipulate variable as above.

Here is a demo:

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 image,
 Button["LoadPicture", 
  image = Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen", def]], 
  Method -> "Queued"],
  {{image,<<< IMAGE HERE >>>},None},
  {{def, "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram\\Research\\Mathematica\\11.0\\Documentation\\English\\System\\ExampleData\\*.tiff"}, None}

 ]
```